# Bouncing scrollbars in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, firefox

I've recently added some CSS3 support for an animated loading icon to work on different - if not all - browsers.
Chrome was the first, no problems there.

But when I tried it in Firefox and Internet Explorer, the scrollbar keeps "bouncing" in a small area of the total height of the scrollbar.

It looks like a hyperactive dog bouncing up and down, yet the animation works completely.
Here's the code I added for IE/FF/... support that made the animation work and the scrollbar bounce:

```
i {
    /* Add vendor prefixes for other browsers */
    animation: rotateThis .75s infinite linear;

    font-size: 15pt;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
/* Add vendor prefixes for other browsers */
@keyframes rotateThis {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

The code above makes a Bootstrap loading icon rotate continuously, that's it.
**Here's a fiddle, for anyone interested: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XhNky/)** (I suggest viewing it in Google Chrome to avoid any misconceptions of the desired result)

Any ideas on why this happens and how it can be fixed? I'm puzzled.

Comment: Check the outline; http://jsfiddle.net/XhNky/1/
 You should try using a fixed height/width for the icon. If it works you can answer your own question ;)

Comment: @RenéGeuze So by adding "height" to the page every spin, it makes the scrollbar look like it's bouncing? Alright, I should be able to fix that. Thanks for the indication!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set width and height for the icon

Updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XhNky/3/)

CSS

```
.icon {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}
.outer {
    text-align: center
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="outer "><i class="icon  glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! works like a charm. I was planning on answering the question myself, but you beat me to it :)